# Php floating if statement Confused

Tags: php

```
function is_decimal( $it )
{
    return is_numeric( $it ) && floor( $it ) != $it;
}

if (is_decimal == true){
    echo "Decimal";
}
```

This gives me an error even though the int is not a decimal (float). Can someone help me. Thanks
 It works fine for a decimal but not for an int.

Comment: What is `if_decimal` ?????

Comment: A function I created which checks if theres a decimal or not

Comment: I see a function called `is_decimal()` is this just a typo

Comment: And `is_decimal()` requires a parameter, you dont pass one

Comment: yes my bad i thought i wrote it correctly

Comment: And `(is_decimal($somevariable) == true){` probably required an IF ie. `if (is_decimal($somevariable) == true){`

Comment: I think I already did

Comment: sorry forgot to put that in but still the same problem

Comment: This is a mess. Please delete all your comments and edit your answer. Make sure we see your actual code. Make it easy for people to help you. Many people probably don't feel like puzzling your additions together. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Include your input and the error message you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, when you call a function with a parameter you have to pass a parameter!

```
function is_decimal( $spaces )
{
    return is_numeric( $spaces ) && floor( $spaces ) != $spaces;
}

$tst_var = 1.99
if (is_decimal($tst_var) == true){
    echo "Error 3: Decimal causing Error as carpark can't have decimal spaces available.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `if(is_numeric( $spaces )){ ... }` work for int, float even if they are represented by string

Comment: Can you show me a further demonstration thanks

Comment: But I need it to separate decimals from ints